# CSV To SQL Converter

Tags: c#, sql, csv

I'm currently having some issues with my CSV to SQL Converter. With this being my third week of learning C# I'm starting to grasp some stuff but this is going over my head a bit.

What I'm trying to do is have the Top row/Titles taken down split into each individual title and then for the SQL code through that rather than entering it manually like I've done. Below you can see some of my code that I've built so far.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // your code here 
            string CSVFilePathName = @"C:\\CSV\\reg.csv";
            string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
            string[] Fields;
            //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
            // get regs from filename
            // get fieldnames from Lines[0] (first line of file)
            // create a loop for fields array
            string hdr = Lines[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                CSVTextBox.AppendText(Fields[0] + "," + Fields[1] + "," + Fields[2] + "," + Fields[3] + Environment.NewLine);
                // need a for loop for each field
                // for (
                                    SQLTextBox.AppendText("INSERT INTO[dbo].[REGS]([SESTYPE],[REG],[LFL],[SUBVER]) VALUES('" + Fields[3] + "'" + Fields[0] + "'" + Fields[1] + "'" + Fields[2] + ")" + Environment.NewLine);
                //     }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error is " + ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }

    }
```

This all runs at the moment, I'm just struggling to get the titles to become part of the code. Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Remove the try catch. If you get an Exception, you should read, understand and clear off.
For your SQLTextBox: I recommend to use the String.Format function. This allows you to create strings with different values, but is much, much easier to read.

For the titles: Use your variable *hdr* This should contain the title. Then you can split it via string.Split(',') or string.Split(';'), depending on your delimiter